# Sort by Category; Element Has Multiple Categories (isotope.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to make use of isotope.js (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html) to live-sort a grid of elements. The plugin itself is quite straightforward, but I've encountered a small snag that I can't find any documentation on.

I want to sort the elements by their 'category'. This in and of itself is quite simple, however: the catch is, each element could potentially have multiple categories.

So, for example, the element I'm trying to sort might look like this:

```
<div class="sortable-element" data-category="category_1">
```

But what I wanted it to have multiple categories? ie:

```
<div class="sortable-element" data-category="category_1 category_2 category_3">
```

Or:

```
<div class="sortable-element" data-category="category_1, category_2, category_3">
```

Does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Comment: Which criteria will be used to sort those?

Answer (score 0):

you cant have multiple values in your sort by field. But you can have multiple field, like in this example:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item" data-color="yellow">
    <p class="number">3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-color="blue">
    <p class="number">2</p>
  </div>
  ...
</div>

var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  getSortData: {
    color: '[data-color]',
    number: '.number parseInt'
  },
  // sort by color then number
  sortBy: [ 'color', 'number' ]
});
```

See this webpage: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/sxAJL

Comment: I'm trying to sort by dynamic content, though. For example, suppose I'm on a page archiving webcomics. I want to be able to filter by the characters that appear in the webcomic. So one webcomic might have three characters, another might have six, another might have three but a different three than the first... how could I filter by that if Isotope (inexplicably) doesn't allow a sort field to have multiple values?

Comment: what is now more important? Sorting or Filtering? For your example seems filtering more important... It is for sure not possible to sort a field which has multiple values, on which pos should isotope bring the field? One the one from the first ore the second value, it can only on one position?!

Comment: For Filtering there are good examples http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/filtering.html

Comment: Sorry, it's filtering for sure, I've been using the terms interchangeably. I need to FILTER the results to only, for example, webcomics that have the chosen character in them.

All of the filtering examples use only a single value per field. I don't know if it's possible apply multiple values to each field and if it is how to do so. Via class name, via data attribute? Isotope.js's documentation does not include this information.

Comment: So, to use the 'red, yellow, and blue divs' example from their documentation, assume there is a div that is BOTH red AND yellow. I need to be able to filter it to 'red' and see that div, OR filter it to 'yellow' and still see that one.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I made for your a quick example for understanding:

```
<section id="options" class="clearfix">
  <ul id="filters" class="option-set clearfix" data-option-key="filter">
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*">show all</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Superman">Superman</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Supergirl">Supergirl</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Spiderman">Spiderman</a</li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Batman">Batman</a</li>
  </ul>
</section> <!-- #options -->

<div id="container" class="clearfix">
  <div class="item Spiderman Superman Hulk">
    <p>Comic 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item Captain-America Superman Supergirl">
    <p>Comic 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item Nightcrawler Sub-Mariner Marv">
    <p>Comic 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item Hulk Nightcrawler Batman">
    <p>Comic 4</p>
  </div>
    <div class="item Nightcrawler Hulk Supergirl">
    <p>Comic 5</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyPNQJ